# Is there a way of inserting javascript function as an onclick attribute, or href attribute to a hyperlink in sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

So, is it possible to add a link as follows (or some equivalent to this)

```
<a href="javascript:somefunction()">Click Here</a>
```

into the Sharepoint page, but without using Content Editor Web Part.

Basically I want to open a new list item form from another site collection's list, and I need to open it in modal dialog, and I have working javascript function that allows me to do just that, but I can't call that function from the link itself because Sharepoint keeps stripping my javascript code when I'm saving the changes. In the other hand, CEWP can not be added to the sharepoint page itself.

Can I do anything about this?

Comment: Do you insert any customizations to your page like jQuery library or other javascripts scripts?

Comment: Yes, I have a javascript function that is displaying a form in modal dialog. I can keep that script in masterpage, but I'd rather add it directly to the page itself

Comment: Why you can't add Content Editor Web Part, it will not even be visible on the page... Just include the `<script>` block in that and from Web Part properties choose Chrome Type=None

Comment: For some reason, Sharepoint does not allow me to add content editor on this page. It's disabled in the ribbon.

Comment: Use SP Designer to add your javascript code. It will allow you to add.

Comment: No, I tried with SPD, it also keeps removing my javascript

Comment: Can you try to create a 'new' form in SPD for the target list/library and try referencing your script file. You can use code (features) to provision javascript on that page (if you are open to that) but that would be an overkill for something of this nature.

Comment: What if you try adding Content Editor Web Part from SPD..? Is it not shown in the list..?

Comment: Hello Arslan. Sorry for not answering any sooner, but I've got a baby several days ago so I was not online, nor working... I've tried to add it from SPD and it's disabled even there. I don't see any AllowWebParts, or AllowLayoutChanges tags as well...

Answer (score 1):

As your problem is to make a call to `somefunction()` try to bind it in your JavaScript file.

**jQuery solution:**

```
$('#link-id').click(somefunction);
```

**Pure JavaScript:**

```
var anchor1 = document.getElementById("link-id");
anchor1.onclick = function() { 
    somefunction(); 
    return false; 
}
```

Both require to add id attribute to your link (of course you may use also a `class="..."` or anything else).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I liked this approach very much, and I was convinced it's gonna work, but it does not. When I do this the link is not clickable at all. It looks like a link, but mouse cursor now even does not change when I hover over it, nor anything happen when I click it.